# Drawing consisting of two linked lists with pointers and values

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I just started taking an algorithms course, however, due to some family issues, I did not have a chance to participate in the first two lectures. Now I'm in a bit of a pickle, because I don't understand much of what is going on.

[image: Task]

Above is a picture of a task that I need to solve. From what i understand, L0 is a list containing all values of S and L1 is a list containing all values of S and a pointer to the corresponding value in L0. However, what I do not understand is when they start bringing in delta and drawings. If anyone could clarify the meaning of delta and the parameter delta = 3, I might have a chance of solving it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, 'delta' is just a parameter. You can call it 'd' if you prefer.

L0 contains all elements of S (as a linked list).
L1 contains every 'delta'th element of S as a linked list, with a pointer to the corresponding value in L0.

So the answer to 2.1 is something like:

```
L0: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
    ^              ^              ^
    |              |              |
L1: 1 -----------> 4 -----------> 7
```

That is, L1 contains the 0th, 3rd, and 6th (i=0, delta, 2*delta, where delta=3) element of S.

Comment: Ooooooh! So the delta is basically telling me only to take every delta'th element of L0 into L1. Okay, that makes perfect sense. Thank you!