# Search element in linked list with delta and x as parameters

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

recently started an algorithms class and having trouble with one of the tasks.

[Link to task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHK3g.png)

Above is a link to the task that I have to finish. Usually, if I want to check a linked list, i run through the list and check if the element X is in the linked list. However, now there are two singly-linked lists and a parameter delta, which has confused me. 
Any help in regards to how to implement delta and two linked lists is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55088731/905902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does confuse you?

Run through the second list to find small range quickly, then make small-step search in the first list. Keep previous item of the second list to provide link to ther start of needed range

```
 l0(0)   l0(1)   l0(2)   l0(3)  l0(4)  l0(5)  l0(6) ...
 ^                          ^                  ^
 l1(0)                    l1(1)                l1(2)
                            ^                  ^  
                           prev                current
```

Comment: Im confused about what the paramter Delta does in this case and what it is used for. And i'm not quite sure what you mean by making a "fine-tune" search in the first list

Comment: Imagine paper vocabulary with bookmarks for every letter. To find word "key", you read bookmarks until bookmark "k" is met, then open book at this bookmark and check words starting from letter k. So you don't need to check 1000 pages, only 26 bookmark and about 20-40 pages.

Comment: So if I first find a small range and then make small-step search, will that mean that the time complexity will be θ(n log n)?

Comment: No. Delta step is Sqrt(n), so the second list contains about Sqrt(n) items, and complexity is O(Sqrt(n)) + O(Sqrt(n))  = O(Sqrt(n))